# Error in Logcat java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError?

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I am trying two create an existing project in the eclipse, but while running the project an error occurred `"Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library not found"` in the Log.
I had already added the Library to the Project references...

Can you explain the reason for this??

Comment: does it specify the name of missing library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `UnsatisfiedLinkError` happens when a *native code library* cannot be found.  Adding a project reference is not sufficient to fix this.

In general, you would cure this by either putting the relevant native library in some directory on the native library search path, or updating the search path.  If you needed to load the code into Eclipse itself, the changes would typically done in the eclipse.ini.  If you needed to load the code into a Java app launched from Eclipse, you would modify the run configuration.

In this case, it would seem that you are trying to run a library on the Android emulator that depends on a native library for the android platform.  I don't know how you would deal with that ... or even if it is possible to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by a missing native method. That can be caused by running an app on a device or emulator that doesn't support some api you are using.

One thing you can try is temporarily reduce the target SDK level to the minimum SDK level you have specified in your manifest and see if any error messages pop up. That's a signal that your minimum SDK level is wrong for the apis you are using.

Comment: If caused by SDK mismatch he would likely get `NoSuchMethodError`

Answer (score 0):

If you are run on android device. Then uses adb push command to push the library to /system/lib path on android 
devices.